# Embedding a UIPageViewController in a UIViewController stops paging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I'm working on a modally-presented lightbox and I'm having trouble embedding the `UIPageViewController` in the parent view controller (to allow for "floating" elements that are not paged).

Below is the source for the containing `UIViewController`. Its Xib contains a `UIButton` and a `UIView` with an outlet called `workingArea`.

The array of views (`vc`) is populated with a test class that places a solid-color image in the center of the view.

```
@interface LightboxContainerViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *vcs;

@end

@implementation LightboxContainerViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UIPageViewController *lb = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    lb.dataSource = self;

    self.vcs = @[
                 [[LightboxViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LightboxViewController" bundle:nil andImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]]],
                 [[LightboxViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LightboxViewController" bundle:nil andImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]]],
                 [[LightboxViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LightboxViewController" bundle:nil andImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]]]
                 ];

    [lb setViewControllers:@[self.vcs[0]]
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:NO completion:nil];

    lb.view.frame = self.workingArea.bounds;
    [self.workingArea addSubview:lb.view];
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
     viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.vcs indexOfObject:viewController];

    if(currentIndex == 0){
        return nil;
    }
    return [self.vcs objectAtIndex:--currentIndex];
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.vcs indexOfObject:viewController];
    if(currentIndex == self.vcs.count - 1){
        return nil;
    }
    // Output selected VC
    return [self.vcs objectAtIndex:++currentIndex];
}

-(NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return self.vcs.count;
}

-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}

#pragma Modal view management

- (void) presentModal {
    [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:self animated:YES completion:nil];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    }];
}

- (void) dismissModal {
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    }];
}

#pragma mark UI interaction

- (IBAction)closePressed:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModal];
}

#pragma mark UIPageViewControllerDatasource

-(UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return self.vcs[index];
}

@end
```

The first `UIViewController` of the three shows up fine, and there are three dots in the scrolling indicator, but I cannot swipe between pages.

I've set breakpoints, and `viewControllerBeforeViewController`/`viewControllerAfterViewController` are never called, although `presentationIndexForPageViewController` is.

This code seems to work fine when the datasource methods are included directly in a `UIPageViewController`, it only gets stuck like this when embedded in a parent `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lb` is released after `alloc`. So it can't do anything

```
UIPageViewController *lb = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
```

You should create a var in .h or in .m file like:

```
@interface LightboxContainerViewController ()
{
   UIPageViewController *lb
}

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *vcs;

@end
```

then

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.



       lb = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
        // .....
    }
```

Comment: Adding the UIPageViewController as a property did the trick. Weird that it manifested in that way, I would have expected there to be an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: "Weird that it manifested in that way, I would have expected there to be an EXC_BAD_ACCESS". What do you mean? add as property causes crash?

Comment: Nope, I would have expected that my original code would have crashed if the `UIPageViewController` had been dealloced. Your solution works great.

Comment: Based on @matt's answer, calling `addChildViewController` also retains the `UIPageViewController`, which is probably the better way of doing it.

Comment: Got it. If my answer works. Please mark it is the answer. About crash. If you take `UIPageViewController` does something, it will crash. Try to subclass `UIPageViewController` to see it.

Comment: With as property, you can check and do something else with `UIPageViewController`. Mean you have a handle point to `UIPageViewController`. With `addChildViewController`, you won't do anything with `addChildViewController` anymore. And you can leave it.

Comment: True, although in my case I don't need to do anything to the `UIPageViewController` once loaded :) Added an answer with what I actually did for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here's the change I ended up making and why (new lines marked NEW):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // ...

     UIPageViewController *lb = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    lb.dataSource = self;

    // Populate self.vs here

    // NEW: Added this line to ensure we retain a reference to lb
    [self addChildViewController:lb];

    [lb setViewControllers:@[self.vcs[0]]
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Set page view controller's view's frame to match host view's frame
    lb.view.frame = self.workingArea.bounds;

    // NEW: Added this line to notify lb of what's happening
    [lb didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [self.workingArea addSubview:lb.view];
}
```

This is the same pattern as used for Container Views, and ensures that we retain a reference to the `UIPageViewController` so that the delegate can be found on interaction.

I don't need to do any additional work with the `UIPageViewController` once loaded, so this is sufficient for my purpose.